# C#: How would I get the current time into a string?

Tags: c#

How could I get the current h/m/s AM time into a string? And maybe also the date in numeric form (01/02/09) into another one?

Answer (score 94):

I'd just like to point out something in these answers.  In a date/time format string, '/' will be replaced with *whatever the user's date separator is*, and ':' will be replaced with *whatever the user's time separator is*.  That is, if I've defined my date separator to be '.' (in the Regional and Language Options control panel applet, "intl.cpl"), and my time separator to be '?' (just pretend I'm crazy like that), then

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt")
```

would return

```
01.05.2009 6?01 PM
```

In most cases, this is what you want, because you want to respect the user's settings.  If, however, you **require** the format be something specific (say, if it's going to parsed back out by somebody else down the wire), then you need to escape these special characters:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM\\/dd\\/yyyy h\\:mm tt")
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy h\:mm tt")
```

which would now return

```
01/05/2009 6:01 PM
```

---

**EDIT**:

Then again, if you ***really*** want to respect the user's settings, you should use one of the standard date/time format strings, so that you respect not only the user's choices of separators, but also the general format of the date and/or time.

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
DateTime.Now.ToString("d")
```

Both would return "1/5/2009" using standard US options, or "05/01/2009" using standard UK options, for instance.

```
DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()
DateTime.Now.ToString("D")
```

Both would return "Monday, January 05, 2009" in US locale, or "05 January 2009" in UK.

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()
DateTime.Now.ToString("t");
```

"6:01 PM" in US, "18:01" in UK.

```
DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
```

"6:01:04 PM" in US, "18:01:04" in UK.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString()
DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
```

"1/5/2009 6:01:04 PM" in US, "05/01/2009 18:01:04" in UK.

Many other options are available.  See docs for [standard date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: Upvoted, because this can be huge, especially when moving data between systems.

Answer (score 23):

You can use format strings as well.

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"); // includes leading zeros
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy"); // includes leading zeros
```

or some shortcuts if the format works for you

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Either should work.

Comment: You've got those backwards, should be hh:mm:ss for Time, and dd/MM/yy for Date.

Comment: For 24-hour clock use HH:mm:ss

Comment: For 12-hour clock use hh:mm:ss tt

Comment: Just to be clear: lower-case 'm' gives you the minute, while upper-case 'M' gives you the month.  This is different from VB or Excel, where case doesn't matter and context is used to determine which value to return.

Comment: Thanks for updating that.  Heh, that's what I get for going by memory.   ;)

Comment: Be careful of a race condition when accessing DateTime.Now. Your code, for example, will fail badly if the first call to DateTime.Now happens just before midnight and the second one just after. The result would be almost 24 hours out.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that the solution is to grab Now into a local var:

var now = DateTime.Now;
...

Answer (score 18):

Method to  get system Date and  time  in  a  single string

```
public static string GetTimeDate()
{
    string DateTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");   
    return DateTime;
} 

sample OUTPUT :-16-03-2015 07:45:15
```

Answer (score 11):

> ```
> DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt")
> DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
> ```

Here are some [common format strings](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Comment: handy cheat sheet and shameless plug: http://john-sheehan.com/blog/net-cheat-sheets

Answer (score 5):

Be careful when accessing DateTime.Now twice, as it's possible for the calls to straddle midnight and you'll get wacky results on rare occasions and be left scratching your head.

To be safe, you should assign DateTime.Now to a local variable first if you're going to use it more than once:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var time = now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
var date = now.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
```

Note the use of lower case "hh" do display hours from 00-11 even in the afternoon, and "tt" to show AM/PM, as the question requested. If you want 24 hour clock 00-23, use "HH".

Answer (score 2):

```
string t = DateTime.Now.ToString("h/m/s tt");
string t2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
string d = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx