# How to set current time to a value

Tags: c#

I was just wondering if there is a way to get the current time and set it into a value.

If its 12:06 AM.. I want to get that time and set it into currentTime.

Example

```
float currentTime = 0;
currentTime = 12.06;
```

Comment: why your finding it so difficult ? did you searched on google about DateTime class ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414733/c-how-would-i-get-the-current-time-into-a-string

Comment: are you sure you want the currentTime  to show like "12.06" if the time is 12:06 cause if you are taking hours it should be 12.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the DateTime class would be ideal for this, and to work out the difference between 2 date/times:

```
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
DateTime start = new DateTime(2011, 12, 5, 12, 6,0);

double hours = (end - start).TotalHours;
```

The subtraction of DateTime objects results in a TimeSpan object that you can use to see the hours/minutes etc.

Answer (score 3):

try DateTime class

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
DateTime currentTime;

currentTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Something similar. I just want to be able to take the time when someone clocks in and clock outs. Then subtract those two times and get the hours worked. But how do I subtract strings?

Comment: @ClaudiuBadau, you don't subtract strings.  You would subtract `DateTime` objects.  Also, you mention nothing of that in your question.

Comment: @ClaudiuBadau, Yes use the DateTime class as Inuyasha mentions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Well if you really what it as a float then try:

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now; 
float currentTime = float.Parse((currentDate.Hour > 12 ? currentDate.Hour -12 :
currentDate.Hour)  + "." + currentDate.Minute);
```

I wouldn't recommend comparing dates or time with floats. A better options would be to use timespans.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use floats or strings. You can do all kinds of cool things using DateTime.

Here's how you'd get the hours that someone worked:

```
var clockIn = new DateTime(2011,12,4,9,0,0);   // December 4th, 9 AM
var clockOut = new DateTime(2011,12,4,17,0,0); // December 4th, 5 PM

var duration = clockOut - clockIn;             // TimeSpan

Console.Write(duration.TotalHours);            // 8
```

Answer (score 2):

A few people have mentioned how, but as a 'better' recommendation you should use

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow
```

Otherwise you have issues when the clocks go back, if your timing code is run on those days. (plus it is far easier to alter the UTC time to local time than it is to convert a '1am' to UTC (as there will be two of them when the clocks go back)

Comment: @Nick tell me about it, I once argued with my old colleagues about UtcNow telling them that, every year their log records on the days the clocks go back are useless.

Comment: Its definitely a gotta moment when you forget/ don't use UtcNow.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
 DateTime StartTime=StartTime value;
 DateTime CurrentTime=DateTime.Now;
 TimeSpan dt = CurrentTime.Subtract(StartTime);
```

In `dt` you will get a working time period.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a `Timespan` instance for time related values, you can use the flexibility to get the required values like

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
ts.ToString("hh:mm") // this could be what you are looking for
```

You could then use `ts.TotalHours` which would give you fractional hours (as a `double`) else you could construct a string specifically using `ts.Hours` ..`ts.Minutes` play around and it could be prove useful.

Comment: am looking current time without midnight values using timespan @V4Vendetta

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the difference between two times, then do this:

```
DateTime dateOne = DateTime.Parse(enteredTime);
DateTime dateTwo = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan difference = dateOne - dateTwo;
```